# "autoreconf: not found" error during making qemu-1.4.0

Tags: make, qemu

I was `./configure`'d the qemu-1.4.0 and during `make` it cause:

```
(cd /home/amin/Simulate/qemu-1.4.0/pixman; autoreconf -v --install)
/bin/sh: 1: autoreconf: not found
make: *** [/home/amin/Simulate/qemu-1.4.0/pixman/configure] Error 127
```

Now, I can't find how to pass this error.

Thanks.

Comment: this exact question came up at a hackathon I went to a few months ago. It was useful not just online. idk, im feeling nostalgic.

Answer (score 224):

I just had this problem myself, and the solution I found in reading [the autoconf manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html) which states autoreconf runs autoconf which I did not have installed.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

and the autogen script I am using now works.

Comment: I've been surprised how many folks this has helped. I was at a hacker conference last week, where I met a kid with this exact question, and this same solution. unbelievable.

Answer (score 107):

Try installing `autoconf` package.

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```

Comment: All you need it `autoreconf`, `dh-*` packages are only needed when using debhelper (for packaging `.deb`s)

Comment: in 13.04 it seems to be `sudo apt-get install autoconf` (without the "re")

Comment: @einSelbst Thanks a lot! Your comment is very useful for 13.04 :D

Comment: `autoconf` in 14.04 also !

Comment: Can confirm this works in 16.04

Comment: `autoconf` in Debian 9.x "stretch" also !

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, should install `dh-autoreconf` : `sudo apt install dh-autoreconf`

Answer (score 10):

I used to search for package first:

```
# apt-cache search autoreconf
   autoconf2.13 - automatic configure script builder (obsolete version)
   dh-autoreconf - debhelper add-on to call autoreconf and clean up after the build
```

Then install what I need:

```
# apt-get install dh-autoreconf
```

Comment: Actually, you need both <code>autoconf</code> and then <dh-autoreconf>, in case you do not have both of em'.

Comment: soufrk, any details ? Here is guide: http://qemu-buch.de/de/index.php?title=QEMU-KVM-Buch/_QEMU%2BKVM_unter_Linux , nothing about necessity to install autoconf

Comment: This should be the answer.